# AngularJS - Insert ng-repeat into another one between two TR

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

My question is - I think - pretty simple.

I have a table, a classic one. In this table, I want to display values of two arrays named **networks** and **channels**.

Each **network** in **networks** could contain **channels** but **not all**.

What I want is to display all the **networks** and their related **channels**.

In ***DIV*** or ***TD*** in ***TR*** it's simple but I can't do this with multiple ***TR***.

*Example :*

```
<tr ng-repeat="network in networks">
     <td>{{network.Name}}</td>
     <td ng-repeat="channel in channels | filter: { networkId: network.networkId}">{{channel.Name}}</td>
</tr>
```

Works like a charm!

But I'm searching thing like this :

```
<tr ng-repeat="network in networks">
     <td>{{network.Name}}</td>
     <td ng-repeat="month in year">{{month.Name}}</td>
</tr>
<tr ng-repeat="channel in channels | filter: { networkId: network.networkId}">
     <td>{{channel.Name}}</td>
     <td ng-repeat="month in year">{{month.Name}}</td>
</tr>
```

But I know that is not the good code to do this :)

Someone know how to do that ?
I don't want to change the ***TABLE*** by ***DIV***.

Kind regards !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each `ng-repeat` has its own scope so your network is not available on the second `TR` repeat.

If you really want to stick with table, you can create a table inside your tr like this:

```
<tr ng-repeat="network in networks">
     <td>{{network.Name}}</td>
     <td ng-repeat="month in year">{{month.Name}}</td>
     <td>             
         <table>
            <tr ng-repeat="channel in channels | filter: { networkId: network.networkId}">
               <td>{{channel.Name}}</td>
             </tr>
         </table>
     </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: I can't use _**Table**_ in the **TR** because other **TD** are displayed. The complete line code is : `<tr ng-repeat="network in networks"><td>{{network.Name}}</td><td ng-repeat="month in year">{{month.Name}}</td></tr><tr ng-repeat="channel in channels | filter: { NetworkId: network.NetworkId }"><td>{{channel.Name}}</td><td ng-repeat="month in year">{{month.Name}}</td></tr>`

Comment: code is not readable in comment, could you please update your question with that? @NivekLR

Comment: check the update, I reckon you better move out of table if this is the case since the UI doesn't look good with this approach @NivekLR

Comment: OK. Thank you for your time. I'll do it :)